# how to make connection with database qt

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

the connection between qt and my database don't work 
I have created the database with PHPMyAdmin and the path is in the same project file of qt and added the libmysql.dll and libmysqld.dll in the bin 
this is my

.pro

QT       += core gui sql

source file

```
#include "mainwindow2.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow2.h"
#include "QtSql"
#include "QSqlDatabase"

 void MainWindow2::on_connect_clicked()
{

QSqlDatabase db;
db.addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setUserName("root");
db.setPassword("");
db.setDatabaseName("as");


QString contenu = ui->le->text();

ui->label->setText(contenu);


if(db.open()){
    w =new MainWindow(this);
    w->show();

}else{

    QMessageBox::information(this,"kiw","kiw");


}
}
```

Comment: What is the error you encounter ? By the way, you forgot to set the port.

Comment: when i clic connect it's always the else : QMessageBox::information(this,"kiw","kiw");

Comment: @Ian_salvatore add `qDebug() << db.lastError().text()` before `QMessageBox::information(this,"kiw","kiw");`

Comment: "Driver not loaded Driver not loaded"

Comment: yes mysql is installed in my computer , how to check if install in qt ?

Comment: mmm, One thing is that you have the mysql: libmysql.dll driver installed, but another thing is that you have to compile and install the MySQL plugin for Qt. You have to compile the plugin for Qt as noted in the docs:  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qmysql-plugin-on-windows

Comment: I remember I had similar problem (it was MariaDB not pure MySQL though). It was related to default user. Are you sure this user you used in code has required privileges?

Comment: yes he had all required privileges